# Can a Windows phone be traced without a SIM and the battery?

Tags: mobile

I lost my lumia 800 mobile two days back. If the sim and battery are removed, can it be traced with the IMEI number by the cops if I lodge a complaint? Or can the location be traced if a new sim is used in the lost mobile..? Please tell me a good way to trace my mobile. !

Answer (score 2):

Very fortunately, radios cannot operate without power. Some systems such as RFID provide external power in the radio signal, but those are all very short range. Very basic AM radios can be powered by the signal itself, but that power is very very minimal. It's certainly insufficient to drive a transmitter.

If your phone is not powered, it can only be identified by physically checking the serial number.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Lucas Kauffman here and say Yes, it can.

It is entirely possible to track the phone if you have the IMEI and the phone is currently being used with a new SIM. Simply because they are both used to identify with the network.

Now, if your question was 'Will they' instead of 'Can they' I would have to agree with Lucas 100% -- There is no way they would spend the time and money to track a lost cell phone unless it somehow posed a national security threat.

With a price tag of about $250 new, the Lumia 800 being stolen wouldn't even qualify as grand theft in my home state. It would cost much more to locate the phone than it would to buy a new one.

I don't really like cell phone insurance, but this is why the policies exist. Sorry for your loss

Comment: And how exactly could this worth with the battery removed?